# SSRS with parameters export to excel using textbox

Tags: excel, vb.net, reporting-services, export

I have a Reporting Services (SSRS) rdl report with parameters. The user can select multiple values in one of the parameters.

I need to export the report to Excel file using a hyperlink with a button.

Here is my current URL:

```
=Globals!ReportServerUrl & "/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?" & Globals!ReportFolder & "/" & Globals!ReportName & "&Command=Render&rs:Format=Excel"
```

The report cannot run without the parameters.

Is there any VB code that can help me in this case?

Comment: You need to add the parameters to the URL string as well like `&parameter1Name=parameter1value&parameter2name=parameter2value`. [Here are the MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155391.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: yes, but if there is multiple parameter there is a problem to sent them via url

Comment: If you have a multi-value parameter you just need to use the following syntax: `&parameter1name=parameter1value1&parameter1name=parameter1value2...&parameter1name=parameter1valuen`. If you need to unpack a multi-value parameter to send in the URL, you can do something like: `="ReportServer...RestOfReportPath/YourReportName" & "&ParameterName=" & Join(Parameters!ParameterName.Value, "&ParameterName=") & "&parameternName=parameternValue" & "&Command=Render&rs:Format=Excel"`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how I form the URL with all the different types of parameters. For your reference, this is the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/pass-a-report-parameter-within-a-url?view=sql-server-2017).

> to use Null as a parameter [Parameter Name]:IsNull=True

```
=Globals!ReportServerUrl + "/ReportServer?" 
 + Replace(Globals!ReportFolder, " ", "+") + "%2f" 
 + Replace(Globals!ReportName, " ", "+") + "&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=Excel"
 + "&single_parameter=" + Parameters!single_parameter.Value 
 + "&mutliple_parameters=" + Join(Parameters!mutliple_parameters.Value, "&mutliple_parameters=") 
 + IIf(IsNothing(Parameters!start_date.Value), "&start_date:isnull=True", "&start_date=" & Format(Parameters!start_date.Value, "dd-MMM-yyyy"))
 + IIf(IsNothing(Parameters!end_date.Value), "&end_date:isnull=True", "&end_date=" & Format(Parameters!end_date.Value, "dd-MMM-yyyy"))
 + "&boolean_parameter=" + CStr(Parameters!boolean_parameter.Value)
```